# Where to free up memory allocated (for union) with _strdup in lex / yacc program?

Tags: c, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

I have defined the following union structure in my yacc / bison file:

```
%union
{
    int num;
    double dbl;
    char ch;
    char *str;
}
```

In my lex / flex file I have the following match:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9"_"]* { yylval->str = _strdup(yytext); return id; }
```

My question, where do I put the code to free the "str" ?

```
free(yylval->str);
```

Assuming this is OK.  Note that I get an access violation if I put the "free" before the string duplication:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9"_"]* {
    free(yylval->str);
    yylval->str = _strdup(yytext);
    return id; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there are two things I do with a "str" (char *) in the yacc / bison file, either:
1. I make another copy using strdup (and later on I free up the copy)
2. I don't do anything explicitly with the "char *" (string), for example, in the lex / flex file:

```
";" { return semicolon; }
"foo"|"FOO" { return foo; }
"bar"|"BAR" { return bar; }
```

...and in the yacc / bison file:

```
%token<str> cmd foo bar
...

line:
   cmd prm semicolon { func($2); }
   ;

prm:
    foo { $<num>$ = FOO_ID; }
    |
    bar { $<num>$ = BAR_ID; }
    ;
```

Are you eduffy suggesting that I should free up the original char string only in the first case?

In the rest of my program I always call free (on the destination) before calling _strdup, to clear out anything stored previously, this works OK and does not cause an access violation.  Also what happens to the "yylval->str" memory if it is not freed, does it get freed when yylval goes out of scope?  I'm confused.

(Update) I think I found the solution by adding the following line to the yacc / bison file:

```
%destructor { free($$); } <str>
```

(Another update)
...also adding free to the action for the appropriate token (assuming strdup was used in lex file on "id") e.g.

```
match:
   id prm semicolon { func($2); free($1); }
   ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to free it?  What are you doing with the string in the semantic actions in your bison file?  If you simply store the pointer, then there's nothing to free (yet).  If you make another copy of it, then free it immediately.